# Swift Use of unresolved operator '=~'

Tags: swift, operators

I'm trying to find a code for swift password strength checker, then I see [this from github](https://gist.github.com/chamrc/4b74d0f6caa844116150) I fix some codes but there's a operator that I don't understand, it's `=~`

This is my code

```
enum PasswordStrength: Int {
    case None
    case Weak
    case Moderate
    case Strong
    static func checkStrength(password: String) -> PasswordStrength {
        var len: Int = password.count
        var strength: Int = 0
        switch len {
        case 0:
            return .None
        case 1...4:
            strength += 1
        case 5...8:
            strength += 2
        default:
            strength += 3
        }
        // Upper case, Lower case, Number & Symbols
        let patterns = ["^(?=.*[A-Z]).*$", "^(?=.*[a-z]).*$", "^(?=.*[0-9]).*$", "^(?=.*[!@#%&-_=:;\"'<>,`~\\*\\?\\+\\[\\]\\(\\)\\{\\}\\^\\$\\|\\\\\\.\\/]).*$"]
        for pattern in patterns {
            if (password =~ pattern).boolValue {
                strength += 1
            }
        }
        switch strength {
        case 0:
            return .None
        case 1...3:
            return .Weak
        case 4...6:
            return .Moderate
        default:
            return .Strong
        }
    }
}
```

and my error `Use of unresolved operator '=~'` was pointing at `=~`, what's the meaning of it and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=~` seems like a custom operator (or maybe the pattern matching operator `~=` was different in previous Swift version, but I doubt that, since the pattern matching operator cannot handle regex matching or at least cannot handle it in Swift 5).

You can replace the `=~` with `if password.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) != nil` to check if a regular expression matches your password.

Also, `enum` cases should be lowerCamelCase

Full working code:

```
enum PasswordStrength: Int {
    case none
    case weak
    case moderate
    case strong

    static func checkStrength(password: String) -> PasswordStrength {
        let len = password.count
        var strength: Int = 0
        switch len {
        case 0:
            return .none
        case 1...4:
            strength += 1
        case 5...8:
            strength += 2
        default:
            strength += 3
        }
        // Upper case, Lower case, Number & Symbols
        let patterns = ["^(?=.*[A-Z]).*$", "^(?=.*[a-z]).*$", "^(?=.*[0-9]).*$", "^(?=.*[!@#%&-_=:;\"'<>,`~\\*\\?\\+\\[\\]\\(\\)\\{\\}\\^\\$\\|\\\\\\.\\/]).*$"]
        for pattern in patterns {
            if password.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) != nil {
                strength += 1
            }
        }
        switch strength {
        case 0:
            return .none
        case 1...3:
            return .weak
        case 4...6:
            return .moderate
        default:
            return .strong
        }
    }
}
```

You can also simplify the `for` loop by using a where clause like this:

```
for pattern in patterns where password.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) != nil {
    strength += 1
}
```